# LVM (seemingly) only using one device

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space, lvm, lvm2

I've inherited a machine with 2 physical drives:

1. a ~1tb ssd
2. a ~3tb spinning disk

Here're the filesystems from `$ df -h`:

[[image: output of df -h]}

Note that `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is almost full; it's where a db is writing regularly

But the 2.7Tb `/dev/sda1` has plenty of room.

What I want: IDEALLY, the db would be moved/ written to the spinning disk, freeing the faster ssd for more time intensive tasks.  I WOULD SETTLE FOR just having them together in one VG -ie, the SSD.

note that `$ sudo pvscan` yields

```
PV /dev/nvme0n1p3   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [952.36 GiB / 2.36 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [952.36 GiB] / in use: 1 [952.36 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

Looks like only one device has been mapped to a PV; my research suggests I need to 1) make a new PV via pvcreate, 2) extend the existing vg via extendvg.

And incidentally vgscan and lvscan show only one group.

If I try to map the spinning drive via `$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda1`, i get:

```
Can't open /dev/sda1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

Any help about what i'm missing would be appreciated:

Finally, here is the ouput of `$ sudo fdisk -l`

[image: fdisk -l output]